# HTML/CSS: Having trouble allowing Navigation Bar and Title of the website on the same horizontal line

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I'm having trouble putting the heading of my website in the same horizontal line as my navigation bar and social media logo. Currently, my code only allows me to place the heading on the above line as the social media and navigation bar. Since I started programming with HTML/CSS couple days ago, I've searched all the resources online but cannot find what the issue is.

Here is my code:

```css
.top {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  z-index: 100;
}

.top p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.center a {
  color: rgb(224, 224, 228);
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.center a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(224, 224, 228);
}

.nav a {
  color: white;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
}

.logos {
  float: left;
}

.logos a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logos a {
  color: white;
}

.top {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="top">
  <div class="center">
    <h><a href="J.html">J[a]son</a></h>
    <p>Personal Blog</p>
  </div>
  <div class="top">
    <div class="logos">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jason.ahn.129/" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jasonja-ahn/" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="J.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#photography">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#coding">CODING</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you used twice the class `.top` which has a width of 100%, `.center` seems a block too, spanning 100% of the width avalaible.

Comment: Should I delete the width in .top..? Not sure how to go about it..

Comment: If you wnt the 3 container on the same line, take a look at flex https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ . most of the time `width:100%` for a block container is a bad idea , if borders, or padding in the parent, then it's too much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a flex example , without width:

You were really close .

```css
.top {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: black;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  z-index: 100;
}

.top p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.center a {
  color: rgb(224, 224, 228);
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.center a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(224, 224, 228);
}

.nav a {
  color: white;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
}

.logos {
  float: left;
}

.logos a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logos a {
  color: white;
}

.top {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="top">
  <div class="center">
    <h><a href="J.html">J[a]son</a></h>
    <p>Personal Blog</p>
  </div>
  <div class="top">
    <div class="logos">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jason.ahn.129/" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jasonja-ahn/" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="J.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#photography">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#coding">CODING</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```